# Bourbon - File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, stylesheet, sass

I recently upgraded to rails 3.1 and also installed the [Bourbon gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon) in my rails 3.1 app. Added this to my gemfile: `gem 'bourbon'` and ran `$ bundle install` but when in my application.css.scss I add the `@import "bourbon";` line, i get the following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer ...
```

here is my application.css.scss file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope. 
 *= require_self
*/
@import "bourbon";
@import "scaffold.css.scss";
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

any idea how to load Boubon? what am I doing wrong?

I am guessing there need to be some files that need to be generated for rails to access bourbon library, no?

Any help or clues will be much appreciated

Comment: also tried running `rake bourbon:install` but had no difference

Comment: any help or clues will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alik, try specifying the gem version number in your gemfile. https://rubygems.org/gems/bourbon

gem "bourbon", "~> 0.2.1"

rake bourbon:install will not help you on rails 3.1+